# How to use emacs tuareg mode effectively to manage an OCaml project?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I am using OCaml for a project with 20 - 50 files inside. Also I am using `emacs + tuareg`.

Syntax highlight is well done by tuareg and generally it is good using emacs for one file editing.

However, for the project files, I need to frequently switch between files together with folders, how can i use emacs as also a project manager? like eclipse?

How can I have a file / project tree there just like Eclipse does?

Also how do people manage a huge bunch of files (just like core library or batteries-included) effectively? It seems emacs is good for single file editing, but not good at managing a virtual project.

thanks

Comment: Check out [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) and see if it meets your needs.